# Repeated permutation of set gives the identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations

Suppose I have a permutation $P$ on a set ${a_1,a_2,...a_n}$ such that it has the following properties:

1. $P$ is not the identity permutation.
2. $P\circ P\circ P...=P^k=i_a$, the identity permutation.

That is, permuting the set k times gives the identity permutation. How do I find a relation between $k$ and $n$? I have tried the following:

Given that a permutation is a rearranging of elements, you know that changing the element k times at index $r$ will always give you $a_r$. That means that you are taking $1$ element out of the total number of possible elements you can map to after each iteration of $P$, or $k-1$ elements before the final iteration, after which you will always map to $a_r$. Therefore, $k$ must be a multiple of $n$.

However, I don't know if this is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take $n = 3$ and let $P$ permute $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then $P^2$ is the identity, but $2$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: I assume that $k$ is minimally chosen. Then you're asking about element orders in the symmetric group. By Lagrange's theorem, $k$ divides $n!$. You may be interested in Landau's function, giving the largest $k$ for every $n$.

Comment: Consider the [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of the group action. The orders of each orbit have to divide $k$, so $n$ is a sum of some divisors of $k$ (the divisors can repeat). That tells us little about $n$ and $k$. Indeed, you can take $P$ to have one orbit of length $2$ and a lot of orbits with lengths equal to $1$. In this example $k < n$, but we can also have $k>n$, say take $(123)(45)$. For the maximal $k$, see the above comment.